# Running a LINQ query for multiple years

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the below query that I need to run for multiple years say between 2010 and 2016.

FirstValidYear in the below query is an integer year value I get from a different query. Whatever value that is say if its 2010, then I am looking for a way to run the query for years 2010 through 2016 (between FirstValidYear and FirstValidYear +6)

```
var ValidationList = (
                      join t1 in table1 
                      join t2 in table2 on t1.colID equals t2.ID
                      where t1Field.IsActive && // Run this for FirstValidYear , FirstValidYear +1, FirstValidYear +2 , ..., FirstValidYear + 6)
                      select new
                      {
                          t1.Name,
                          Year = FirstValidYear, // Needs to be incremented for each run
                          needsNewTest = !isValidYear(
                              FirstValidYear,
                              Convert.ToDateTime("6/1/" + (FirstValidYear - 1).ToString()))
                      }
                     ).ToList();
```

FirstValidYear is a database column which has a year say 2010..so the query needs to be run for years 2010 , 2011,...2016.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code seems to be missing some pieces, so I'll just include the relevant line:

```
int firstValidYear = GetFirstValidYear();
int sixYearsLater = firstValidYear + 6;

where x.WhatIsTheComparisonField >= firstValidYear &&
      x.WhatIsTheComparisonField <= sixYearsLater
```

Comment: I apologize I didn't explain enough. The year range is not always 2010 and 2016, that was just an example I used. It should be between whatever FirstValidYear is and FirstValidYear + 6.

Comment: Can you update your question to show where `FirstValidYear` comes from?

Comment: I added some explanation for FirstValidYear. That's a precalculated integer value I have. If FirstValidYear is 2004, I would like to run the query for 2004 thru' 2010. if its 2008, then run the query for years 2008 through 2014 and so on. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll have to to include some more information for anyone to answer your question. What does "run this query for x years" mean. Do you literally want to run the query 6 times, or do you want to query across a range? If it's a range, what db field are you trying to compare to? Please add a more complete example if you hope to have this answered.